# Почему очень долго запускаются даже самые легкие скрипты внутри VirtualBox?

Tags: python, pywinauto, uiautomation

Почему внутри VirtualBox у меня очень долго запускаются скрипты, конвертированные в EXE? Сам EXE пробовал запускать и напрямую, и через командную строку, и через батник. Внутри скрипта запуск софта и его автоматизация действий через pywinauto. На хосте они за секунду запускаются, а внутри виртуальной машины  20-40 секунд или могут вообще не запустится... В чем может быть причина? Уже неделю+ копаюсь и никак не пойму в чем дело! Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: банально может оперативки мало, добавьте подробностей как минимум о виртуальной машине и хосте

Comment: Vitrual Box с Win 10 внутри(и на хостовой), 8 гигабайт оперативной памяти(16 на хосте). Хост: Intel Core i3-7100U (2.4 ГГц) / RAM 16 ГБ / SSD 512 ГБ / Intel HD Graphics 620. Виртуалка сама по себе работает оч шустро.

Comment: Всё хорошо, но `i3`... 2 ядра, 4 потока, думаю, просто ядер/потоков маловато, чтобы и хост и виртуалку успевать обслуживать. Как минимум 1 поток уходит на саму операционку и в хосте и в виртуалке, в итоге скрипту хорошо если 1 поток достанется.

Comment: @OpylatOleksandr что со скоростью если запустить не конвертированные скрипты `.py`? в конечном счете речь может дойти до содержимого самих скриптов, так что будьте готовы.

Comment: Кстати, да. Распаковка интерпретатора из .exe файла может быть самой тяжёлой операцией. Уж лучше поставить Python и пакеты в самой виртуалке.